# Why am I getting a "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error when I try to install React-Bootstrap using "npm i react-bootstrap"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, npm, visual-studio-code

I'm following a full-stack MERN tutorial, and after using the "npx create-react-app" command to create the react application smoothly, everything is compiling & running properly, but as SOON AS I try to install the React-Bootstrap library using the regular "npm i react-bootstrap" in the command line of Visual Studio Code OR Windows CMD, I'm getting the "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". Could somebody PLEASE explain how to get rid of that error so that I can install React-Bootstrap? I'm unable to proceed further, and I would really appreciate if someone could help me out!

Comment: can you provide us a screenshot of the errors you're getting ?

Comment: @DaimellahSofiane I've just uploaded a screenshot. Kindly have a look. What do you think the issue is? I had recently updated my npm to version 15+ by uninstalling the older Node.js and then downloading and installing Node.js again, and my React is version 17+ as well.

Comment: @tpnprogsdev there is no such thing as `npm of version 15+` yet. did you mean `node` instead?

Comment: @falinsky Yes, Yes, I meant Node.js version 15+. Sorry about that. So, what do you think?

Comment: please share your package.json file content

Comment: i recommend you to use the LTS version of nodeJS and not the latest one which is version 14.15.0

Comment: @tpnprogsdev you can try to remove the whole `./node_modules` directory and run `npm i` first

Comment: @DaimellahSofiane But the latest version is 15.12.0, and the LTS version is 14.15,0! Which one of these should I be using?

Comment: always use LTS versions

Comment: @DaimellahSofiane Alright. I'll try the LTS version of Node.js immediately, and let you know of the outcome.

Comment: @DaimellahSofiane Thanks a lot! Installing the LTS version of Node.js fixed the problem! I don't understand, how literally, an updated version of Node.js with "latest features" could throw errors/get stuck on installing libraries via npm!

Comment: The LTS versions of all software are the tested and trusted ones, yes the latest versions are the ones that contain the latest features and so on, but as they are new, they also aren't free of bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So one of the users in the comments suggested installing the "LTS" version of Node.js, instead of the one that's shown with "latest features" on their website. And indeed, installing the LTS version of Node.js fixed the problem! I don't understand though, how literally, an updated version of Node.js with "latest features" could throw errors/get stuck on installing libraries via npm. Regardless, this particular issue has now been resolved.

Comment: worked for me too
to install nvm `https://gist.github.com/d2s/372b5943bce17b964a79`
to install lts `nvm install --lts`
then `npm i --save react-bootstrap` finally worked

Answer (score 0):

Updating Node using `nvm install --lts` solved it for me and I was able to install the package.